# How add ID element to the specific class line?

Tags: javascript, class, addition, element

I would like to add an ID to a line that contains a class with the specified name. eg. If the website will block "div" or "li" that contains a class with names such as "name-1 name-2 name-3"  This function detects a class called "name-1" and insert element id="menu" that the line looks like this: . Can you help?
I tried that:

```html
<div class="menu-item menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children">
I am a DIV or LI element
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction2()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction2() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item-has-children")[0];
        x.document.createElement("id");
}
</script>
```

Comment: FWIW - be careful that you don't end up adding the same ID to multiple elements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need `document` this what you need:

```
function myFunction2() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item-has-children")[0];
        x.id="menu"
}
```

But you should look into jQuery for things like that:

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').attr('id','menu')
```

All you need to do for using jQuery is to add this tag:

`<script src=https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js></script>` to your HEAD element.

---

You can start learn jQuery by learning about selectors, and attr. Using this links:

- [jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [jQuery attr function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: jQuery to change the id? Really?

Comment: jQuery to get by class name AND change the ID.

Comment: @Aminadav Notice that if you have no html element with the class `menu-item-has-children` you end up with an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

When you get that element by class name, use following way to give id to yur element

```
<script>
function myFunction2() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item-has-children")[0];
    $('.'+x).attr('id','menu');
}
</script>
```

Comment: OP - be aware that this is using jQuery. For vanilla js, look at @Aminadav's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
function myFunction2() {  
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item-has-children');
  
  if (elements.length) {
    elements[0].id = 'menu';
  }
}
```

```css
#menu {color:red;}
```

```html
<div class="menu-item menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children">
  I am a DIV or LI element
</div>

<div class="menu-item menu-item-object-custom">
  I am another DIV or LI element
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction2()">Try it</button>
```